# Laravel Mix: ValidationError: CSS Loader has been initialized using an options object that does not match the API schema

Tags: node.js, laravel, npm, webpack, laravel-mix

I recently tried to run `npm run dev` and also `npm run watch`, but I got an error after 80% got compiled. I tried googling it but didn't find the solution to it. Below is the error which I get in my console.

> ERROR in ./resources/sass/frontend/app.scss Module build failed (from
> ./node_modules/mini-css-extract-plugin/dist/loader.js):
> ModuleBuildError: Module build failed (from
> ./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js): ValidationError: Invalid
> options object. CSS Loader has been initialized using an options
> object that does not match the AP I schema.
>
> - options.url should be one of these:    boolean | object { filter? }    -> Allows to enables/disables `url()`/`image-set()` functions handling.    -> Read more at
>   https://github.com/webpack-contrib/css-loader#url    Details:
>
>   - options.url should be a boolean.
>   - options.url should be an object:
>     object { filter? }
>     at validate (E:\Web Projects\project\node_modules\webpack\node_modules\schema-utils\dist\validate.js:105:11)
>     at Object.getOptions (E:\Web Projects\project\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:527:19)
>     at Object.loader (E:\Web Projects\project\node_modules\css-loader\dist\index.js:31:27)
>     at processResult (E:\Web Projects\project\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:701:19)
>     at E:\Web Projects\project\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:807:5
>     at E:\Web Projects\project\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:399:11
>     at E:\Web Projects\project\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:251:18

**webpack.mix.js**

```
const mix = require('laravel-mix');

mix.setPublicPath('public')
    .setResourceRoot('../')
    .vue()
    .sass('resources/sass/frontend/app.scss', 'css/frontend.css')
    .sass('resources/sass/backend/app.scss', 'css/backend.css')
    .js('resources/js/frontend/app.js', 'js/frontend.js')
    .js([
        'resources/js/backend/before.js',
        'resources/js/backend/app.js',
        'resources/js/backend/after.js'
    ], 'js/backend.js')
    .js('resources/js/global.js', 'js/global.js')
    .js('resources/js/Banners/banner.js', 'js/banner.js')
    .extract([
        // Extract packages from node_modules to vendor.js
        'alpinejs',
        'jquery',
        'bootstrap',
        'popper.js',
        'axios',
        'sweetalert2',
        'lodash'
    ])
    .sourceMaps();

if (mix.inProduction()) {
    mix.version();
} else {
    // Uses inline source-maps on development
    mix.webpackConfig({
        loader: 'url-loader',
        devtool: 'inline-source-map'
    });
}
```

Both `Frontend.scss` & `Backend.scss` are not getting compiled or mixed and throws up an error given above. When I tried to comment it, it ran properly as expected, but without commenting it, it doesn't. I don't know where I am going wrong here. I also tried to run `npm rebuild node-sass` and then again tried to run `npm run prod`, `npm run dev` & `npm run watch`, but none worked.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As a workaround, downgrade your css-loader package to a 5.x version.

```
npm install css-loader@5.2.7 --save-dev
```

Comment: Wonderful! Thanks a lot this worked, but I didn't understand why was the previous `css-loader@6.2.0` creating the above issue? Can you please brief the answer with the reason, because I think a lot more people might be facing this issue if it is a version update. Also if you find my question worth please do upvote. Thanks once again.

Comment: Yes, I would like to know as well, since I am getting the same problem and would like to understand that.

Comment: @HardikSisodia
Similar problem for me using https://github.com/rappasoft/laravel-boilerplate.  Had to downgrade to use Mix.